# Rearrange from $f(r)$ to $r(f)$?

Tags: functions

I'm trying to understand a set of equations from a paper. The Photo shows the problem. The aim is to solve for $r$.

Can anyone explain how it is possible to go from $f(r)$ to $r(f)$ or have I completely misunderstood what they have done? I only have GCSE math so an intuitive explanation and a point at the right place to look up more information would be great.

These are the equations:

$f(r) = \frac{V(r)}{V_{total}}$

$f(r)= \frac{\frac{1}{3}(r^3-R^3)d\Omega}{\frac{1}{3}((R+T)^3-R^3}$

$f(r)= \frac{r^3-R^3}{(R+T)^3-R^3}$

Generally, we are interested in $r$ as a function of $f$, and rearranging the equation gives us the following::

$r(f)^3= ((R+T)^3-R^3)f -R^3$

Taking cube root gives the formula:

$r(f)= \sqrt[3]{((R+T)^3-R^3)f -R^3}$

Thank you!

[image: Problem]

[Original paper - this is from Appendix A](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1053811915000038?via%3Dihub)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of misprints in some of the equations, so I will present an account of the calculation that I believe is required (I do not have access to the paper, so only the picture in the question is used).

There are two concentric spheres with radii $R$ and $R+T$ (hence $T$ is thickness of region) and a solid angle $d\Omega$ [steradians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steradian) which enables one to write an expression for the corresponding volume between the two spheres. This volume is denoted by $V_{total}$ in your first expression, and is the difference between the volume  at $R+T$ and the volume at $R$ for the solid angle $d\Omega$:

$V_{total} = \frac {1}{3} ((R+T)^{3} - R^{3}) d\Omega$

What is required also is the fraction of this volume occupied at radius $r$ into the region ($r$ is measured from the origin). This means that $r>R$ and is denoted in the first equation as $V(r)$

$V(r) = \frac {1}{3} (r^{3} - R^{3}) d\Omega$

$f(r)$ is the fraction of the volume of the region contained up to $r$ and is given (with some cancellations) by:

$f(r) = \frac { r^{3} - R^{3}}{(R+T)^{3} - R^{3} }$

Note that $f(R) = 0$ and $f(R+T) = 1$ demonstrating this this is a fraction (essentially proportion).

The task is to find the fraction $f$ given a radius $R < r < R+T$, which involves inverting this equation:

$f \times [(R+T)^{3} - R^{3}] = r^{3} - R^{3}$

giving

$r^{3} = R^{3} + f ((R+T)^{3} - R^{3})$

or

$r = \sqrt[3]{(R^{3} + f ((R+T)^{3} - R^{3}))}$

We see from this that for $f=0$ $r=R$ and for $f=1$ $r=R+T$.

Comment: Thank you for a great answer Roy, it helped a lot!